# Put legend and labels to dtwclust plot

Tags: r, plot, cluster-analysis, legend, dtw

I used the dtwclust package in R to obtain the clusters in the picture.

```
dtw_cluster2 = tsclust(transdatawide2, type="partitional",k=4,preproc = zscore,
                  distance="dtw_basic",centroid = "pam",trace=T)

plot(dtw_cluster2)
```

[image: clusters]

I want to change the label x, where the numbers appear for the real dates and also add the legend to know which time series correspond to what. 
Do you know how to do it?

```
head(transdatawide2)

     2015-01-06  2015-02-03  2015-03-02  2015-03-03
 A    0.00000    0.00000        0.0      0.00000
 B    0.10000    0.10000        0.1      0.00000
```

Answer (score 0):

Use **labs.arg** argument. You can find more details here [dtwclust documentation](https://www.rdocumentation.org/packages/dtwclust/versions/3.1.1/topics/dtwclust-methods)

with the `plot(dtw_cluster2) + labs(title = "New plot title", x = "New x label")`

or you can also use `plot(dtw_cluster2) + xlab("New x label")+ ylab("New x label") + ggtitle("New plot title")`

Hope this is useful

Comment: Note that the linked documentation is for a very old version, that website has not updated in a while. [This one](https://rdrr.io/cran/dtwclust/) is up to date, and you can always check for the newest at [CRAN](https://cran.r-project.org/web/packages/dtwclust/index.html).